# SP2010 VS workflow that sets up a site

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-server

I'm attempting to essentially recreate the functionality of Project Server, such that when I add a new project to our Project List and check the "Create Site" option, a workflow kicks off and creates a new site using a specific custom template we have. I know that this can't be done with a SharePoint Designer workflow, so I've resigned myself to using Visual Studio.

The problem is, I'm fairly new to VS workflows and have no idea where to start code-wise. I know enough to create a new workflow project in VS2010, but that's about it. Can someone post example code or links that would assist in doing this?

I know the logic of the workflow would be as follows:

> 1. Workflow kicks off on new item creation or update
> 2. Workflow checks to see if "Create Site" value is YES or NO
> 3. If YES, workflow would then create the site using a specific template at the designated location. A value in the list item would be
>      used as the URL for the site.
> 4. Site would most likely just inherit permissions, but potentially we could also make the person designated as the Project Owner the site
>      owner as well, giving them full permission to the site after creation.
> 5. Lastly, the workflow would add a comment to a History field on the project item, noting the date & time that the site was created.
> 6. The final step would be to send an email to the Project Owner with a link to the site. Without SharePoint Designer's interface, I have no
>      idea how to compose an email in a workflow, so I will definitely need
>      some instruction there in detail.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help and/or get me pointed in the right direction.